# Django Download file specfic file

Tags: python, django

I have generated the file and saved in the following directory: `project/media/` following code is setup, but not able to download the file from the media. Not able to download, Can you help, thank you

Files are generated and upload to MEDIA folder, Inside the folder there are multiple files.

VIEW.py

```
file_list = ['file1','file2','file3']
def download(request):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, '/')
    response = ""
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        for file in file_list:
            if 'data1' in request.POST and 'file1' in file:
                file_wrapper = FileWrapper(file(file_path,'rb'))
                file_mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(file_path)
                response = HttpResponse(file_wrapper, content_type=file_mimetype)
                response['X-Sendfile'] = file_path
                response['Content-Length'] = os.stat(file_path).st_size
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s/' % smart_str(file)
    return response
```

HTML

```
<form method="POST" id="data1"> {% csrf_token %}
...
<button id="data1" type="submit" name="download" class="card-link">Download1</a>
<button id="data2" type="submit" name="download" class="card-link">Download2</a>
</form>
```

URL.py

```
urlpatterns = [ path('download', views.download, name='download'),]
```

ERROR

```
if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: move `<button>` inside form

Comment: sorry, with my original code, it is inside the `form`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the error, thanks all, I didn't use `response['X-Sendfile'] = file_path`